# Android Exoplayer unsupported profile 4 for video/mp4-es

Tags: android, video-streaming, http-live-streaming, exoplayer

This is a strange issue.

When a video is transcoding a mpeg2 recording to HLS on the backend, it plays fine in the Exoplayer Demo player.

However, once that has HLS transcode is complete, the video can no longer be played.  Here is the error in the log

```
10-26 09:12:21.030 24468-24691/org.mythtv.android D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllStagingAnimators on 0xb3888900 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0xa86d1260
10-26 09:12:21.165 24468-24468/org.mythtv.android W/VideoCapabilities: Unrecognized profile 2130706433 for video/avc
10-26 09:12:21.184 24468-24468/org.mythtv.android W/VideoCapabilities: Unrecognized profile/level 0/0 for video/mpeg2
10-26 09:12:21.185 24468-24468/org.mythtv.android W/VideoCapabilities: Unrecognized profile/level 0/2 for video/mpeg2
10-26 09:12:21.185 24468-24468/org.mythtv.android W/VideoCapabilities: Unrecognized profile/level 0/3 for video/mpeg2
10-26 09:12:21.205 24468-24468/org.mythtv.android I/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported profile 4 for video/mp4v-es
```

I am not finding a whole lot of information on this issue. It is not really an exception that is bubbling up to the application.

Comment: I'm getting the same error when trying to configure a MediaCodec used to record the screen with MediaProjection.  But the error only occurs on one of three devices I'm testing (Nexus 7).  Did you find a solution?

Comment: No. And I have an open issue on the github tracker as well. No response there either.

Comment: Link to the issue tracker ?

Comment: Same issue face while using Rewarded Video Ads using AdMob

Comment: Similar problem here: `I/VideoCapabilities( 4718): Unsupported profile 4 for video/mp4v-es`

Comment: Has anyone found a solution? Same error using exo player with flutter